# Do we need a [non-java] tag?

Tags: feature-request

When we talk about programming in Android or ask for a sample code in Android, for example, the *default* answers will mostly be made in Java Language. But today we have so many ways to create programs for Android that do not need to step on Java's World (ie: html5/js/css).

Anyway the users are pleased to help in the community, but sometimes they tend to *answer before reading the question* and that turns frustrating when it becomes a waist of time for both.

In my case, for example I always have to be very specific when I need to talk about Android programming in Firemonkey Framework, which uses Object Pascal Language. I have to bold every mention that Java examples won't help here.

I believe there should exist a tag to determine that question, discussion and answers should not have anything about Java in it, considering that Java is a big slice in the cake in SO for many subjects. Java people would see the tag and discard the question and move to something that matters for them.

My suggestion example: `android` `hardware` `camera` **`non-java`** `ionic`

*I know, it is hard to believe, but many users will see* `ionic` *and even then, they will put some Java way to implement a response, not knowing it should be a JS response.*

Comment: This is not what tags are for. I can't be a "non-java" expert. Just downvote the answers that don't bother checking the language and move on.

Comment: Well, tag it with the appropriate language. For instance, if it's [tag:ionic], tag it [tag:javascript], if you want to talk about firemonkey, tag it ... [tag:firemonkey].

Comment: @ChrisHayes Bummer. I was looking forward to getting a [tag:non-java] gold badge.

Comment: You can always add that to your _Ignored Tags_ list if you don't want to see it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The OP is more talking about their own questions, not searching for questions... For the case they're talking about, them ignoring a tag won't help anything.

Comment: "Negative" tags are absolutely not needed. If people are giving useless Java answers to non-Java questions, downvote them.

Comment: If someone doesn't notice something in the question explicitly saying that Java isn't helpful, what makes you think they'll pay attention to a tag?

Comment: Just to make my point, some comments here just prove how some users don't ready and interpret the text properly... Ignored tags wont help in that matter, and Mike, even placing all the right tags, people will make mistakes I have cited.

Comment: @resueman good point.

Comment: Downvote them. if the answer is in the wrong language it is obviously not useful to you.

Comment: The problem I see with a "non-java" tag is it's far too broad. I'm writing a C# question, for example. The "non-java" tag would be accurate to the scope of my question. If I were a new user, didn't know any better, and saw that tag... I'd use it for any question not about Java! Tags are for categorization. How will a "non-java" tag help with that? (Yes, they also help signal to viewers what the question's about, but that should also be made clear in the question.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, we definitely don't need *negating tags* for programming languages.

If you really need to, make it clear in your question, that you're not looking for a solution in the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) language.

If you receive such answers, just downvote, and leave a comment why these aren't appropriate for your question.